# White Space in Key of Associative Array PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm parsing out an HTML table and building an array based on the row values.  My problem is the associative keys that are returned have a bit of white space at the end of them giving me results like this:

```
Array ( [Count  ] => 6   [Class  ] => 30c   [Description] => Conformation Model (Combined 30,57) )
```

So a line like this:

```
echo $myArray['Count'];
```

or

```
echo $myArray['Count '];
```

Gives me a blank result.

for now I've got a pretty hacky work around going...

```
foreach($myArray as $row){

    $count = 0;
    foreach($row as $info){
        if($count == 0){
            echo 'Count:' . $info;
            echo '<br>';
        }
        if($count == 1){
            echo ' Class:' . $info;
            echo '<br>';
        }
        if($count == 2){
            echo ' Description:' . $info;
            echo '<br>';
        }
        $count++;
    }
```

}

The function I'm using to parse the table I found [here](http://blog.mspace.fm/2009/10/14/parse-an-html-table-with-php/):

```
function parseTable($html)
{
  // Find the table
  preg_match("/<table.*?>.*?<\/[\s]*table>/s", $html, $table_html);

  // Get title for each row
  preg_match_all("/<th.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*th>/", $table_html[0], $matches);
  $row_headers = $matches[1];

  // Iterate each row
  preg_match_all("/<tr.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*tr>/s", $table_html[0], $matches);

  $table = array();

  foreach($matches[1] as $row_html)
  {
    preg_match_all("/<td.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*td>/", $row_html, $td_matches);
    $row = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($td_matches[1]); $i++)
    {
      $td = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($td_matches[1][$i]));
      $row[$row_headers[$i]] = $td;
    }

    if(count($row) > 0)
      $table[] = $row;
  }
  return $table;
}
```

I'm assuming I can eliminate the white space by updating with the correct regex expression, but, of course I avoid regex like the plague.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.
-J

Comment: Any specific reason why you're not parsing the HTML directly using a parser like this one? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I have a very specific reason... never heard of it till now ;)  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) to remove leading and trailing whitespace characters:

```
$row[trim($row_headers[$i])] = $td;
```

But don’t use regular expressions for parsing the HTML document; use a proper HTML parser like the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or the one of [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/domdocument) instead.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to change

```
$row[$row_headers[$i]] = $td;
```

to:

```
$row[trim($row_headers[$i])] = $td;
```